# How can I split ("explode") a string into "chunks" that I define?

Tags: php, regex

I wish to use Regex to explode a string into chunks. I'm aware of preg_split() but I'm still struggling with the Regex side of things (and even if preg_split() would help here). I don't even know if I SHOULD use Regex for this to be honest.

Here's what I mean, if I have a string like this:

```
?word word2 word3 "word4 word5 word6" 'word7' word8
```

I want the result to be split into an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ?word
    [1] => word2
    [2] => word3
    [3] => word4 word5 word6
    [4] => word7
    [5] => word8
)
```

Basically a chunks should be separated by a space, but you can place any sort of quote around a set of characters to make that one chunk.

I originally tried exploding by a white space and then concatenating values that start with " or ' until I reach a value that ends with " or '. But I thought there must be a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) with a space as the delimiter argument, and then [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to trim any single quotes

Comment: @bub sorry, I should have been more clear, my bad. I originally tried exploding by a white space and then concatenating values that start with " or ' until I reach a value that ends with " or '. But I thought there must be a better way, searched for about 20 minutes then came here.

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Comment: What about escape sequences? Can there be any in the input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`(?|"(.*?)"|'(.*?)'|(\S+))`](https://regex101.com/r/jB4bV4/1) to capture all required values into group one array with `preg_match_all()`:

```
$str = "?word word2 word3 \"word4 word5 word6\" 'word7' word8";
$regex = "/(?|\"(.*?)\"|'(.*?)'|(\S+))/";
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/0AhB22

Comment: Thank you! I was going to just live with only one delimiter, but this is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Mark Baker for the solution ^.

Used str_getcsv() to separate the string like so:

```
$string = '?word word2 word3 "word4 word5 word6" word7';
$string = str_getcsv($string, ' ', '"', '\\');
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ?word
    [1] => word2
    [2] => word3
    [3] => word4 word5 word6
    [4] => word7
)
```

Comment: The `str_getcsv()` does not allow several delimiters so you can't mix `"..."` and `'...'` in one string. Therefore the `'word7'` the the OP sample input won't be caught.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov - that's why I used an array_walk in my suggestion to trim the `'` characters as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following regex and `preg_match_all()`:

```
$regex = '/(?<=[\'"])(?:[^ "\'][^"\']*)|[^\'" ]+/';
$subject = '?word word2 word3 "word4 word5 word6" \'word7\' word8';

preg_match_all($regex, $subject, $result);
var_dump($result[0]);
```

I've assumed that your chunks don't contain quotes, unless they are used to group multiple words.